# Сопряжение с устройством по bluetooth в приложении kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, kivy, bluetooth

В моём kivy-приложении есть кнопка, которая вызывает popup-окно, где показан список устройств-bluetooth. Также есть кнопки "подключить" и "обновить". При нажатии на одну из кнопок с именами устройств, она подсвечивается другим цветом и остаётся выбранной. Это сделано следующим образом:

```py
class BluetoothPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BluetoothPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
        self.title = "Выберите Bluetooth устройство"
        selected = BooleanProperty(False)

        # Создаем вертикальный BoxLayout для размещения кнопок устройств
        layout0 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)
        self.layout1_1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)
        # Создаем кнопку для каждого устройства и добавляем их в layout
        for device in self.devices:
            btn = Button(text=str(device[1]), size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
            btn.bind(on_release=self.select_device)  # Привязываем функцию к кнопке
            self.layout1_1.add_widget(btn)
        layout0.add_widget(self.layout1_1)
        layout1_2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10)

        # Создаем кнопку "Подключить"
        connect_btn = Button(text='Подключить', size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp', on_release=self.connect_device)
        layout1_2.add_widget(connect_btn)
        # Создаем кнопку "Обновить"
        refresh_btn = Button(text='Обновить', size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
        refresh_btn.bind(on_release=self.refresh_devices)
        layout1_2.add_widget(refresh_btn)

        layout0.add_widget(layout1_2)
        self.content = layout0  # Размещаем layout в контенте

    def select_device(self, instance):
        # Выделяем выбранное устройство другим цветом
        for device_btn in self.layout1_1.children:
            if device_btn.__class__.__name__ == 'Button':
                device_btn.background_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)  # Сбрасываем цвет всех кнопок
        instance.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
          # Задаем цвет выбранной кнопке
```

Теперь мне надо дописать в класс функцию `connect`, которая позволит устанавливать сопряжение с выбранным из списка устройством с целью принятия от него данных.
Для ясности: устройство, с которым надо сопрячь приложение, это усилитель биопотенциалов, который ээг записывает. Собственно, данные от него принимаемые это и есть ЭЭГ.
Было много попыток написать функцию подключения, но стабильно оно не устанавливалось (используется библиотека pybluez22). Вот вырванный кусок из недавней попытки:

```py
self.socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
self.socket.connect((self.selected_amp, 1))
self.socket.bind(("", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
self.socket.listen(5)
bluetooth.advertise_service(self.socket, self.name, service_id=self.uuid,
                                            service_classes=[self.uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
                                            profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])
          
client, client_info = self.socket.accept()
self.root.clear_widgets()
self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_plots, 1 / 256)
```

Видела примеры сопряжений с BluetoothAdapter, но этот зверь мне совсем не знаком, так что по возможности, можно пожалуйста варианты с pybluez. Заранее большое спасибо